# Which type page is prefered when kmalloc is invoked with the argument of GFP_KERNEL solely, unmovable, reclaimable or movable pages?

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

Which type page is prefered when `kmalloc` is invoked with the argument of GFP_KERNEL solely,  unmovable, reclaimable or movable pages? And could you please tell me your reasons?

I think maybe it's reclaimable pages.

Comment: Look in "include/linux/gfp.h".

Comment: @IanAbbott  have read it indeed. Could you please give me some hint?

Comment: It defines the `GFP_KERNEL` macro as a bitwise OR of more primitive GFP macro values that are also documented.

Comment: @IanAbbott Thank you for your attention to this matter. Excuse me, I understand that `GFP_KERNEL` is equivalent to `__GFP_RECLAIM | __GFP_IO | __GFP_FS` and  `__GFP_RECLAIM` is equivalent to  `___GFP_DIRECT_RECLAIM|___GFP_KSWAPD_RECLAIM`. But I really don't think `___GFP_DIRECT_RECLAIM` implies which type of memory is prefered.

Comment: Indeed, there is not enough information from gfp.h alone. As I understand it, the allocator initially tries to allocate from pageblock types implied by GFP request flags and will fall back to allocating from other pageblock types. Since memory allocated with `GFP_KERNEL` is unmovable, it will preferably be allocated from the pool of free "unmovable" pageblocks.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I almost fully understand what you mean. I wonder why memory allocated with `GFP_KERNEL` is unmovable. Could you explain that more in detail for me?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216726/discussion-between-ian-abbott-and-john).